# Wildfly standalone file not being added in dockerfile

Tags: jboss, docker, apache-camel, wildfly

I am trying to create a docker image from wildflyext/wildfly-camel.

In my dockerfile I add various files, including a customized standalone file - standalone-camel.xml

When Wildfly starts, it is specified - somewhere, though am not sure where - to use standalone-camel.xml, and the only file named this is in /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/

So, my dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM wildflyext/wildfly-camel
MAINTAINER ah <me@domain.io>

ENV TMPDIR /tmp/
ENV WFDIR /opt/jboss/wildfly/

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin admin --silent
#ADD psql-jdbc.jar /opt/jboss/wildfly/

#ADD psql-jdbc.jar $WFDIR/standalone/deployments/

#ADD module.xml $WFDIR/modules/org/postgresql/main/
ADD standalone.xml $WFDIR/standalone/configuration/
CMD rm $WFDIR/standalone/configuration/standalone-camel.xml

#ADD standalone-camel.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/configuration/
ADD standalone-camel.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/

#ADD standalone-camel.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/
ADD standalone-camel.xml /opt/jboss/wildfly/



#ADD postgresql-9.4-1201.jdbc41.jar $WFDIR/modules/org/postgresql/jdbc/main/
#ADD psql-jdbc.jar $WFDIR/standalone/deployments/
ADD config.sh $TMPDIR
ADD batch.cli $TMPDIR
#RUN $TMPDIR/config.sh

CMD ["/opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

However, when I build and run the container, it seems that either my file did not get copied, or it is being overwritten - at least the file I standalone-camel.xml file.

Anyone know what might be going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: can you post your Dockerfile, or a complete reproducer?

Comment: Ive added my dockerfile to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your Dockerfile:

```
"CMD rm $WFDIR/standalone/configuration/standalone-camel.xml"
```

It should be changed to RUN parameter.

About your main problem. If you use volume mapper, you need to make sure that it don't use that directory /opt/jboss/wildfly